# Can you interface directly with the ADB?

Tags: android, adb, windows-7-x64, interfacing

I have had no luck finding Drivers to my HTC Desire phone (not X, S or whatever, but the first HTC Desire), and I can't make it work with my laptop for Android App testing.

I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow interface with the ADB directly and make it realize that my phone is there?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the simplest way is to connect your phone to your PC not for charging or developing but as media storage. Windows will try to install the drivers itself. After that you can connect your device also for developing. This - at least - has worked for me.

There is also a possibility to change one of the default drivers. But I'd prefer the first ones. The second works like described here: http://www.waxinlyrical.com/node/10

Comment: I tried the first thing, and it didn't really work. Won't recognize that my phone is connected in the ADB manager. What is the second option you say?

Comment: Did Windows start to install / look for a driver? You maybe need to choose another option. I don't know which are available for you.

Comment: i updated my answer with the second solution. both have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Google USB drivers for your phone (adb).
By downloading http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html  (android sdk, ..) you can download the USB drivers, and the adb too. (adb in sdk/platform-tools, driver in sdk\extras\google\usb_driver after downloading)

In device manager, try to update drivers, and set to find in this folder. Or try to find drivers @ windows update.

To test: adb wait-for-device command blocks until your device shows up.

On your phone check that USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: Is your device shown at device management on Windows? Has it the right driver, or is it unknown or 'other' device?

Maybe HTC sync includes the drivers you need: http://dl4.htc.com/managed-assets/support/software/htc-sync/htc_sync_setup_3.3.21.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. For some reason Windows doesn't recognize the Google driver, you have to manually install it.

1. Open Device Manager and find your device, it should be under Other devices and have a yellow exclamation point on it.
2. Right click and select "Properties" open the Driver tab and choose "Update Driver".
3. Choose "Browse my computer for driver software", then choose "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
4. Choose "Have Disk" now browse to the file you downloaded from Google. I'm at work so I can't tell you exactly where it is, but it should be something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver